# how to insert in multiple sql table with only one function of add in DAL class c#

Tags: c#, mysql

how to insert data in multiple table using only one function????????
how to insert data in multiple table with only one function of add in DAL class c#

```
   public void add(string id,string Name)
{
    string q="insert into t1(ID,name) values('"id"','"+Name+"')";
    cmd=new sqlcommand(q,con);
    con.open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the syntax errors in your example and the use of string concatenation you could write something like this

```
string q=@"insert into t1(ID,name) values('A','ABC');
           insert into t2(ID2,name2) values('B','DEF');
           insert into t3(ID3,name3) values('C','GHJ')";
cmd=new SqlCommand(q,con);
con.open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice that every INSERT refers to a different table with different fields (also more than twos) the only thing to keep an eye open is the semicolon between the INSERT statements. Warning, not every database supports this syntax (For example MS-Access doesn't like it)

Comment: Thnku for your lesson i want to learn something diffrent i need to add in 2 table & sometimes in 3 tables when i insert in two tables there is an exception t3's table txtbox is null